# Apply search columns and export mat table to excel

Tags: html, angular, angular-material-table

I am trying to implement a reports feature in my application which pulls country wise reports for a person logged in. I am getting data from backend and displaying this in a mat table. I want to have different filters based on country, sectors, industries on this data and it should also have the feature to export it.. For the filtering i dont want to run a backend query everytime so i want to filter it in the frontend and export the given data. I tried the table_to_sheet option of xlsx but that only exports the first page of the table. My code:

```
Object:
export interface Reports {
  projectId: string;
  projectName: string;
  industry: string;
  sector: string;
}
```

my table looks like this

[image]

I want to update the data array every time I apply a filter and then export  the same. Can anyone help.

I am assigning the table in ngonInit

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
        this.service.getReports(this.loggedUser, this.role).subscribe
          (
            (res: any) => {
                this.showSpinner = false
                this.showTable = true
                console.log(res)
                console.log(res.reportList)
                console.log('filters: ' +res.reportFilter.countrySet)
                this.dataSourceMyRequests = new MatTableDataSource(res.reportList) ;
                this.countryList = res.reportFilter.countrySet
                this.gcnList = res.reportFilter.countrySet
                this.sectorList = res.reportFilter.countrySet
                //this.dataSourceMyRequests.sort = this.sortRequest
                //this.dataSourceMyRequests.paginator = this.paginatorRequest
                this.showData = true;
            },
            (error) => {
              this.showSpinner = false
              this._snackbar.open('No data found!', 'OK');
              console.log(error)
            }
          )
      }
```

I want to write a filter method like below:

```
filter(searchField, searchValue){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For filtering build a frontend filter that gets applied to incoming array of items. After filtering show only filtered items in table.

If filter returns true, then filteredArray will include it.

```js
filteredArray: any[];

observable.subscribe((allData) => {
  this.filteredArrray = allData.filter((item) => {  
    if (item?.projectId === '123') {
         return true;
    } else if  (item?.projectName === 'name') {
         return true;
    } else {
         return false;
    }
  });
})
```

Then export `filteredArray[]` to xlsx: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-export-excel-xlsx?file=app%2FtableUtil.ts